# Addition formula for spherical Bessel functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, bessel-functions

Graf's addition formula for Bessel functions states that:
$$
H_{n}^{(1)}\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\theta)}\right)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}H_{m+n}^{(1)}(a)J_{m}(b)e^{im\theta}
$$
for $a>b>0$. I would like to know if a similar formula exists for spherical Bessel functions i.e. Bessel functions of half integer order i.e. something like
$$
h_{n}^{(1)}\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\theta)}\right)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}h_{m+n}^{(1)}(a)j_{m}(b)e^{im\theta}
$$
I can't find anything in the literature, but I would like to know for sure that one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graf's addition theorem (9.1.79 [here](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_363.htm))
$$ H_{\nu}^{(1)}\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab \cos(\theta)}\right)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}H_{m+\nu}^{(1)}(a)J_{m}(b)e^{im\theta}$$
holds for arbitrary $\nu$. Setting $\nu = n + \frac12$, we obtain the addition theorem
$$h_{n}^{(1)}\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab \cos(\theta)}\right)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}h_{m+n}^{(1)}(a)J_{m}(b)e^{im\theta} $$
for the spherical Bessel functions. Note that $J_m$, different from your proposal, is a conventional Bessel function.